# Calling summary function inside lapply returning NaN values

Tags: r, dplyr, lapply

Say I have this data frame:

```
df <- structure(list(q1 = structure(c(2L, 2L, 4L, 
3L, 1L, 4L), .Label = c("I dont like\na thing", 
"I really dont like\nthat thing", "I like a\nthing", 
"Ambivalent\nabout the thing"), class = "factor"), q2 = structure(c(3L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L), .Label = c("Neither like\nnor dislike", 
"Somewhat\ndislike", "Somewhat\nlike", "Strongly\ndislike", "Strongly\nlike"
), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I can run the below dplyr chunk without any problem:

```
df %>%
    summarise(question = 'q1',
              n = sum(!is.na(q1)), 
              mean = mean(as.numeric(q1), na.rm = T), 
              sd = sd(as.numeric(q1), na.rm = T), 
              se = sd/sqrt(n), 
              ci_lo = mean - qnorm(1 - (.05/2))*se,  # qnorm() provides the specified Z-score
              ci_hi = mean + qnorm(1 - (.05/2))*se,
              min = min(as.integer(q1)),
              max = max(as.integer(q1)))


# A tibble: 1 x 9
  question     n  mean    sd    se ci_lo ci_hi   min   max
  <chr>    <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <int> <int>
1 q1           6  2.67  1.21 0.494  1.70  3.64     1     4
```

But if I try and put this inside a `lapply()` function and call it on all column names in a list, it returns a bunch of `NaN` and `NA` values.

```
summary_stats <- function(question){
  df %>%
    summarise(question = question,
              n = sum(!is.na(question)), 
              mean = mean(as.numeric(question), na.rm = T), 
              sd = sd(as.numeric(question), na.rm = T), 
              se = sd/sqrt(n), 
              ci_lo = mean - qnorm(1 - (.05 / 2)) * se,  # qnorm() provides the specified Z-score
              ci_hi = mean + qnorm(1 - (.05 / 2)) * se,
              min = min(as.numeric(question)),
              max = max(as.numeric(question))) 
}

colnames <- 
  df %>% 
  select(starts_with("q")) %>% 
  colnames

lapply(colnames, summary_stats)


[[1]]
# A tibble: 1 x 9
  question     n  mean    sd    se ci_lo ci_hi   min   max
  <chr>    <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 q1           1   NaN    NA    NA   NaN   NaN    NA    NA

[[2]]
# A tibble: 1 x 9
  question     n  mean    sd    se ci_lo ci_hi   min   max
  <chr>    <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 q2           1   NaN    NA    NA   NaN   NaN    NA    NA

Warning messages:
1: In mean(as.integer(question), na.rm = T) : NAs introduced by coercion
2: In is.data.frame(x) : NAs introduced by coercion
3: In mask$eval_all_summarise(quo) : NAs introduced by coercion
4: In mask$eval_all_summarise(quo) : NAs introduced by coercion
5: In mean(as.integer(question), na.rm = T) : NAs introduced by coercion
6: In is.data.frame(x) : NAs introduced by coercion
7: In mask$eval_all_summarise(quo) : NAs introduced by coercion
8: In mask$eval_all_summarise(quo) : NAs introduced by coercion
```

Does anyone know where i'm going wrong here? I'd also like to return a single tibble with one row per column fed through to the `lapply` function, instead of one tbl_df per column. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing column names to the function whereas the functions expects column data.

Here is an alternative way -

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

summary_stats <- function(data){
       tibble(n = sum(!is.na(data)), 
              mean = mean(as.numeric(data), na.rm = T), 
              sd = sd(as.numeric(data), na.rm = T), 
              se = sd/sqrt(n), 
              ci_lo = mean - qnorm(1 - (.05 / 2)) * se,
              ci_hi = mean + qnorm(1 - (.05 / 2)) * se,
              min = min(as.numeric(data)),
              max = max(as.numeric(data))) 
}

map_df(df %>% select(starts_with('q')), summary_stats, .id = 'question')

#  question     n  mean    sd    se ci_lo ci_hi   min   max
#  <chr>    <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1 q1           6  2.67  1.21 0.494 1.70   3.64     1     4
#2 q2           6  2     1.26 0.516 0.988  3.01     1     4
```

Comment: This works great. Thanks Ronak! I've changed the line for the mean to `mean = round(mean(as.numeric(data), na.rm = T), digits = 2)` to try and fix the number of decimal points i'm seeing (in my actual, not toy, df). But the output is now `2.360000e+00, 1.219097e+00, 2.770619e-03` for the mean, sd, and se respectively. Do you know how I can print out just the first two digits after the period and that's it?

Comment: run `options(scipen =  99)` in the console.

Comment: Nice~ that's worked, although the min and max values are now NA

Comment: If you have `NA` values in the data use add `na.rm = TRUE` in `max` and `min` function.

Comment: That's done the trick. Thanks so much as always